# Create referential table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I need to create referential table :

[image]

Final result:

[image]

My problem is when `WHEN orsrg.magcode LIKE '12Z%' THEN 'ZirPro'`

How to create dynamically all possibility within like?

Comment: What is your issue?  I don't understand the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a calculated column, so this is always up-to-date:

```
alter orsrg add type_col as
    (case when magcode like '12Z%' then 'ZirPro'
          when magcode in ('27AM') then 'Amherst'
          when magcode in ('12M1', '12M3', '12MC') then 'Mulberry'
     end);
```

If you are going to have a lookup table, then you will need to list all the "12Z" combinations.  Or you would need to use `LIKE` (or a similar construct) for looking things up -- and that would be expensive from a performance perspective.